# Why does binding a variable to the src parameter in the img tag not work in vuejs?

Tags: image, vue.js, bind, src

I have a Vuejs component containing an img tag. I can render the image with no problem if I hardcode the src like this.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- <img class="rotate logo" alt="Vue logo" src="@/assets/abstractwave.png"/> -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "RotatingImage",
    props: {
        filename: String
    },

}
</script>
```

I cannot render the image if I insert bind the src as a prop. As follows... Why is this? What must I change in order to render the image using a prop?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img class = "rotate" alt="Vue logo" :src="`@/assets/${filename}`" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "RotatingImage",
    props: {
        filename: String
    },

}
</script>
```

Upon inspection in the browser, I see that the src path is correct, yet the image does not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make computed property:

```
computed: {
  getImgUrl() { 
     return require(`@/assets/${this.filename}`);
  }
}
```

Then in template bind it:

```
<img class = "rotate" alt="Vue logo" :src="getImgUrl" />
```